# cordova create: TypeError: prompt.close is not a function

Tags: cordova

The call `cordova create MyProject` always throws:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:156
    prompt.close();
           ^
TypeError: prompt.close is not a function
    at Insight.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:156:10)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
```

- Xubuntu 16.04
- node 8.12.0
- cordova 8.1.0
- Gradle 4.10.2

And npm:

```
$ npm version
{ npm: '6.4.1',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  cldr: '32.0',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '60.1',
  modules: '57',
  napi: '3',
  nghttp2: '1.32.0',
  node: '8.12.0',
  openssl: '1.0.2p',
  tz: '2017c',
  unicode: '10.0',
  uv: '1.19.2',
  v8: '6.2.414.66',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

I can not create a cordova project :(

Can someone help me a step further?

Comment: Cordova 8.1.0 has some usage analytics issue. You can degrade back to 8.0.0 using `sudo npm i -g cordova@8.0.0` or use  **--no-insight** option with the commands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here in my Mac I used the command

cordova telemetry off

it worked for me!

Comment: Worked for me in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same issue. Read somewhere (sorry, lost the link) that the problem is somehow related to their usage statistics. The solution was to add the `--no-insight` option, this got it to work for me. Hope it helps